# html does not equal document.childNode[0]

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Below is my code. I dont know why var html is not equal to document.childNodes[0]. It keeps returning false. Any help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var html = document.documentElement;
    alert(html === document.childNodes[0]);
    alert(html === document.firstChild);
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: What's your real goal ? You usually don't make those tests.

Comment: I'm studying JS and this is one of the examples in the book. It just doesnt make sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because your first node is the `DOCTYPE` declaration.

The HTML element is `document.childNodes[1]` in your document.

It's also `document.documentElement` which is more reliable (see [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.documentElement)) if what you want is the `html` element in any HTML document.

Comment: Not always... `document.childNodes[1]` does not output the expected value if you have comments between the `DOCTYPE` and the `<html>` element.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
alert(html === document.firstElementChild);
```